# What is restrictions in java.io for decorating streams?

Tags: java, serialization, io, stream, decorator

I am imagine decorator pattern like this:
[image]

I know that java io uses this pattern.

I feel that exist some restrictions for wrapping object but I cannot understand entire rule.

research code:

### snippet 1 - working code:

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("2.txt");

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStreamWrapper = new ObjectOutputStream(objectOutputStream);     //double wrapping

    objectOutputStreamWrapper.writeObject("this is my string");
    objectOutputStreamWrapper.close();

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("2.txt"));
    ObjectInputStream   objectInputStreamWrapper = new ObjectInputStream(objectInputStream);


    System.out.println(objectInputStreamWrapper.readObject());
    objectInputStream.close();
```

### snippet 2 - not working :

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("2.txt");

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStreamWrapper = new ObjectOutputStream(objectOutputStream);     //double wrapping

    objectOutputStreamWrapper.writeObject("this is my string");
    objectOutputStreamWrapper.close();

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("2.txt"));
    //ObjectInputStream   objectInputStreamWrapper = new ObjectInputStream(objectInputStream);


    System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
    objectInputStream.close();
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1361)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at io.WrappingUnwrappingOrderingTest.main(WrappingUnwrappingOrderingTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

### snippet 3 - not working

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("2.txt");

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
  //  ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStreamWrapper = new ObjectOutputStream(objectOutputStream);     //double wrapping

    objectOutputStream.writeObject("this is my string");
    objectOutputStream.close();

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("2.txt"));
    ObjectInputStream   objectInputStreamWrapper = new ObjectInputStream(objectInputStream);


    System.out.println(objectInputStreamWrapper.readObject());
    objectInputStream.close();
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at io.WrappingUnwrappingOrderingTest.main(WrappingUnwrappingOrderingTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Looks like in file on filesystem stores information about order of stream decoration. It is strange for me.Please clarify this misunderstanding.

Does always should I use stricly same order of decorators for input and output?

Comment: It is absolutely another question!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [constructing an ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29) writes some bytes to the underlying stream:

> Creates an ObjectOutputStream that writes to the specified OutputStream. This constructor writes the serialization stream header to the underlying stream

And similarly, creating an ObjectInputStream reads the serialization header.

So, if you open two ObjectOutputStreams and read using just one, or vice-versa, you won't read as many serialization headers as wrote, causing it not to work, as shown in the stack trace:

> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)

This is something which is quite unique to ObjectOutputStream. Wrapping buffered streams into buffered streams, for example, won't have this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify cause of writing headers to underlying stream?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html. The header contains the stream magic and the stream version.